# Masterpages in JSP

Tags: jsp, master-pages

is there a concept like ASP Masterpages in JSP?

Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to step out on a limb here, and say what you're looking for is [JSP Templates](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/jsp_templates/)

Doesn't work exactly the same way, but it actually looks a little more flexible than MasterPages (Allows you to define multiple areas of the templates to pull different content from).

Answer (score 1):

In the Java world there are multiple solutions to this. My suggestion is to use whatever your framework suggests. For example Struts tiles, JSF Facelets e.t.c You do use a web framework, don't you?

- [Tiles](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/tiles-plugin.html)
- [Facelets](https://facelets.dev.java.net/)

Comment: Google Apps Engine. So not the whole Java API is avaliable.